# Dynamic value for jQuery selector $(dynamiValueHere).show();

Tags: javascript, jquery

I guys, I have a little problem with my jquery script. I have more div and i want display it based on the value of my `<select>`.

This is my code:

```
<select name="stackoverflow" id="stackoverflow">
  <option value="123">123 Value</option>
  <option value="124">124 Value</option>
  <option value="125">125 Value</option>
</select>

<div id="number123" class="hidenumber" style="display: none;">123</div>
<div id="number124" class="hidenumber" style="display: none;">124</div>
<div id="number125" class="hidenumber" style="display: none;">125</div>


<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(window).load(function(){
  $('#stackoverflow').on('change', function() {
    $('.hidenumber').hide();

    $('#number'.this.value).show();
  })
});
</script>
```

The problem is here: `$('#number'.this.value).show();`
How I can write: '#number'.this.value ???

Comment: `$('#number' + this.value).show();`

Comment: in javascript you need to use `+` to concatenate strings. `.` is used to access object properties. Moreover, be careful when you use "this" in jQuery, it may not refer to what you expect. See this: https://jsfiddle.net/bp7Lh9pf/ (either use `this` or `$(this)` in such a case, but keep that in mind for the future.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `+` for string concatenation

```
$('#number'+ this.value).show();
```

```js
$('#stackoverflow').on('change', function() {
  $('.hidenumber').hide();

  $('#number' + this.value).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="stackoverflow" id="stackoverflow">
  <option value="123">123 Value</option>
  <option value="124">124 Value</option>
  <option value="125">125 Value</option>
</select>

<div id="number123" class="hidenumber" style="display: none;">123</div>
<div id="number124" class="hidenumber" style="display: none;">124</div>
<div id="number125" class="hidenumber" style="display: none;">125</div>
```

Comment: I'd rather close this as typo than submit an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` for string concatenation as shown :-

```
$('#number' + this.value).show();
```

and rest of your code is fine.

Comment: @downvoter care to comment plz?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(window).load(function(){
  $('#stackoverflow').on('change', function() {
    $('.hidenumber').hide();
    var num = $('option:selected',this).val();//get the value from selected option
    $('#number'+num).show();//use + to connect string
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="stackoverflow" id="stackoverflow">
  <option value="123">123 Value</option>
  <option value="124">124 Value</option>
  <option value="125">125 Value</option>
</select>

<div id="number123" class="hidenumber" style="display: none;">123</div>
<div id="number124" class="hidenumber" style="display: none;">124</div>
<div id="number125" class="hidenumber" style="display: none;">125</div>
```

Do it like this

Comment: Does `this.value` won't return select value as you used `$('option:selected',this).val()`?

Comment: it will but this is how i do it say jquery it was tag jquery anyway isnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```js
$(window).load(function(){
  $('#stackoverflow').on('change', function() {
    /* only hide visible elements */
    $('.hidenumber:visible').hide();

    $('#number' + this.value).show();
  })
});
```

```css
.hidenumber{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="stackoverflow" id="stackoverflow">
  <option value="123">123 Value</option>
  <option value="124">124 Value</option>
  <option value="125">125 Value</option>
</select>

<div id="number123" class="hidenumber">123</div>
<div id="number124" class="hidenumber">124</div>
<div id="number125" class="hidenumber">125</div>
```